# Finding binomial probability, bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

The following table lists World Series Lengths for  the fifty years from $1926$ to $1975$. Test at the $0.10$ level whether these data are compatible with the model that each World Series game is an independent Bernoulli trial with $p$ = P(AL wins ) = P (NL wins ) = $\frac {1}{2}$

Table
Number of Games ,Number of Years. (respectively)

1) $4, 9$

2) $5, 11$

3) $6 , 8$

4) $7, 22$

Attempt:

I just need help on finding the probabilities.

For example , let X denote the lenght of a World Series.

1) $P( X = 4) $= P (AL and NL wins $4$ times ) =$ 2(\frac{1}{2})^2$

2) $P(X = 5) = \binom {n}{5}(\frac{1}{2})^5(1- \frac{1}{2})^{n - 5}$ I don't even know if this is correct.

3) $P(X = 6)$

I need help on finding probabilities when $X = 5$ and $X = 6$. I think I need to use the binomial distribution.
I don't know what to do. Can someone please help me? and show the formula and help me understand.

For, $P(X = 7) = 1 - P(X - 4) - P(X - 5) - P(X - 6).$ I need part 2) and 3).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to
http://www.insidescience.org/content/are-7-game-world-series-more-common-expected/681
the respective probabilities of 4, 5, 6, and 7 games are
0.125,0.25,0.3125 and 0.3125, for evenly matched teams (*assuming
independently played games*).
Perhaps knowing the answers, you can straighten out your
combinatorial methods. [For example, to have a four game
series either AL needs four in a row (probability 1/16)
or NL does (total of 1/8).]

Your observed frequencies are 9, 11, 8, and 22.
A chi-squared goodness-of-fit test using number of games
as categories, has chi-squared statistic 7.712 with DF = 3,
giving a P-value of  0.05235.

So, at the 10% level, data are not compatible with equally
matched teams and independently played games. At the 5% level
it's a close call because the 'chi-squared statistic'
doesn't have exactly the chi-squared distribution. (I tried
some simulations and mostly the P-values are indeed just above 5%.)

Additional data for more recent years are available in the
Wikipedia 'world series' article. It might be interesting
to see whether you get a different test result for all years,
or for later years.